# c:forEach and primefaces p:panelgrid not working as expected

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jstl

```
<p:panelGrid 
columns="2"         
style="width:800px;">

<c:forEach var="var" items="#{actividadBean.tipoEquipos}" >
    <p:row>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.nombre}" />
    </p:column>
    </p:row>
</c:forEach>

</p:panelGrid>
```

renders both id and nombre (name) in one cell, not in two.

thanks

Comment: do not mix JSF and JSTL tags. simplest thing is to use a `<table>` and `<ui:repeat>` for `<tr>`

Comment: @Michele: Please stop spreading this "do not mix JSF with JSTL" meaningless drivel dating from old days. We're not in 2004 anymore. In the meanwhile, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681

Comment: @demonz: just remove the `<p:row>`. This is not making sense in this specific context. It'll then work as you intented. Whether that's the *right* solution for the concrete requirement is however a different problem.

Comment: @BalusC i heave read it, i'll stop spreading and start using it. you are many steps forward, as usual. and, as usual, thanks for sharing your knowlegde. priceless.

Answer (score 2):

The **c:** tag is a **[JSP - Standard Tag Library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)** tag which wont support with prime-face.
You can use

```
<p:dataTable var="var" value="#{actividadBean.tipoEquipos}">
        <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.nombre}" />
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Else you can also use simple HTML tags

```
<c:forEach var="var" items="#{actividadBean.tipoEquipos}" >
   <tr>
       <td> <h:outputText value="#{var.id}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.nombre}" />
    </td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I will remove the downvote once you explain in proper technical terms the reasoning behind your first statement.

Comment: @BalusC I don't exactly know what really causes the issue, i too had theses kind of issues earlier. When i searched for the details i found that there are some issue with the #{ tag used and also some says that the engine wont detect the JSF codes inside the JSTL tags.

Comment: Well, the downvote stays. The statement *"The c: tag is a JSP - Standard Tag Library tag which wont support with prime-face"* is namely  wrong. Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681 to learn how/what JSTL is actually to be used for.

Comment: @BalusC Now i get..!! Thanks teacher :D  But before making an edit i need to have a clarification, as described in the link above, c:forEach will iterate at first, ie; at view build time. Then it will be generating a set of p:rows with two p:colums inside which is must be working fine. So how does removing the p:row fix the issue here..??